# Completion handler for moveRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there any way to perform a method upon the completion of the animation performed during `-[UITableView moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath]`?

I.e., I'd like the table view to animate moving a cell to its new indexPath, and then once the animation is done, a method should be performed.

Comment: you should put the moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath call in a block and then call the method you want right after the block.  Here's the apple doc on blocks in general, I'm not sure how exactly you'd want to implement it without seeing more stuff:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Let me know if you have more questions

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and the answer is to drop down to `CATransaction`:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
     // Your completion code here
];

[table moveRow…

[CATransaction commit];
```